# $_POST and $_GET convert quote( ' ) to backslash + quote ( \' )

Tags: php, html, post, get

I have this code :

```
<?php  
echo $_GET['user'];
?>

<html >
<head>


</head>
<body>
<form method = "GET"  action="file.php">
    <input type = "text" name = "user"><br> 
    <input type = "submit" value ="submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when I type `'` in the textbox it prints out `\'` instead of `'`.
for example if I type `'hello'` it prints out `\'hello\'`.
So how can I fix that ??

Comment: it "prints out" where? after echo?

Comment: You didnt close your `body` tag. Use [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check for errors.

Comment: [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)?

Comment: stripslashes() thank you billyonecan thats it !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The slashes were added because you have `magic_quotes_gpc=On` in your `php.ini`. Note that this feature is depreacted and you should turn it off in your `php.ini`. It was a former security feature but you should not rely on it. Instead write code for yourself that valides *all inputs* and use prepared statements when you pass inputs to SQL queries or use `escapeshellarg()` if you pass inputs to shell scripts.

However, use [`stripslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the slashes:

```
echo stripslashes($_GET['user']);
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) set in your PHP interpreter. They can be turned off via ini setting.

Answer (score 3):

You should call this function at first.
You don't have to care about backslashes anymore, regardless of your `php.ini` settings.

```
function gpc_clean() {

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $arr = array();
        if (isset($_GET))    $arr[] =& $_GET;
        if (isset($_POST))   $arr[] =& $_POST;
        if (isset($_COOKIE)) $arr[] =& $_COOKIE;
        array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$v) {
            $v = stripslashes($v);
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo stripslashes($_GET['user']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to have it work regardless of whether the feature is turned on or off:

```
function remove_magic_quotes($input) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $input= stripslashes($input);
    return $input;
}
```